# How we can stop a program at certain time in a day@15:30pm everyday…?(It's running every 1 minute)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler

Anyone help me to get code for below conditions...

I would like to run job1 and job2 for every 2 and 3 seconds,
job1 and job2 should start@9:30am in a day..and should stop@17:30pm...! 
job3 @17:31pm daily once only..

```
import schedule
import time

def job1():
   print("I'm working...")
def job2():
   print("I'm not working...")
def job3():
   print("I'll not work...")

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(job1) #For Every 2 seconds
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job2) #For Every 3 Seconds


schedule.every().day.at("17:28").do(job3) #Once in a day

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The numbers in your description, in your comments, and in your code don't agree. It's also not how what the current code is doing is different from what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this into a function and start it in a given time with a scheduler

```
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(job1) #For Every 2 seconds
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job2) #For Every 3 Seconds
```

And you could do the same with canceling the job when you want. So you will have 2 extra job which starts and stops the other jobs.

Comment: To start the job we can use above conditions..but i need a command to stop my job @15:30pm from Mon-Fri...!

Comment: You can return schedule.CancelJob which will cancel it. And at this point you just put if's for checking the days. datetime.datetime.today().weekday() this could be used for this. This will return 0 if its monday and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the nicest way of doing this, but something like this should work. (You obviously can extend the if statement to incorporate only weekdays/exclude holidays etc.)

```
import datetime
import time


def job_a():
    print('a')

def job_b():
    print('b')

def job_3():
    print('3')



start_a = datetime.datetime.now()
wait_time_a = 2

start_b = datetime.datetime.now()
wait_time_b = 5

start_time = 9.30
end_time = 17.31

do_job_3 = False

while True:
    while datetime.datetime.now().hour + datetime.datetime.now().minute/100. > start_time \
        and datetime.datetime.now().hour + datetime.datetime.now().minute/100. < end_time:
            do_job_3 = True
            if (datetime.datetime.now() - start_a).seconds > wait_time_a:
                job_a()
                start_a += datetime.timedelta(seconds=wait_time_a)
            if (datetime.datetime.now() - start_b).seconds > wait_time_b:
                job_b()
                start_b += datetime.timedelta(seconds=wait_time_b)
            time.sleep(1)

    if do_job_3:
        do_job_3 = False
        job_3()

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: oops, gimme a sec

Comment: And My Job1 and Job2 will start@9:30am and stop@3:30pm..in this period job1 will run for every 1 second and job2 will run for every 5 seconds.

Comment: Once, we finished Job1 and Job2 @3:30pm,Job3 should run once@3:31pm...!

Comment: I imagine you can fix that yourself :)

Comment: @Jay Here you go :)

Comment: Hi Nathan,I'm getting date overflow error..with this command  :start_a += datetime.timedelta(wait_time_a)

Comment: @Jay then you should make sure timedelta is in seconds, I added the exact command to the code

Comment: Thanks, Nathan...:)

Comment: @Jay if you're satisfied with the answer, can you accept it so that it's clear for others as well?